# jQuery BBQ Plugin Confusion

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby-on-rails

I am relatively new to JavaScript and jQuery.

I am using the jQuery BBQ plugin to provide back page functionality. I have the following implementation:

```
// Be sure to bind to the "hashchange" event on document.ready, not
// before, or else it may fail in IE6/7. This limitation may be
// removed in a future revision.
$(function(){

  // Override the default behavior of all `a` elements so that, when
  // clicked, their `href` value is pushed onto the history hash
  // instead of being navigated to directly.
  $(".content a").click(function(){
    var href = $(this).attr( "href" );

    // Push this URL "state" onto the history hash.
    $.bbq.pushState({ url: href });

    // Prevent the default click behavior.
    return false;
  });

  // Bind a callback that executes when document.location.hash changes.
  $(window).bind( "hashchange", function(e) {
    // In jQuery 1.4, use e.getState( "url" );
    var url = $.bbq.getState( "url" );

    // In this example, whenever the event is triggered, iterate over
    // all `a` elements, setting the class to "current" if the
    // href matches (and removing it otherwise).
    $("a").each(function(){
      var href = $(this).attr( "href" );

      if ( href === url ) {
        $(this).addClass( "current" );
      } else {
        $(this).removeClass( "current" );
      }
    });

    console.log(url)
    $.getScript(url)

  });

  // Since the event is only triggered when the hash changes, we need
  // to trigger the event now, to handle the hash the page may have
  // loaded with.
  $(window).trigger( "hashchange" );
});
```

Now this works great, if I go direct to mysite.com/brands the URL loads fine, and when I click a tab the URL shows up like this http://localhost:3000/trends#url=/trends/latest which is OK, the back button works when I go through the other tabs on the page.

$.getScript calls the JavaScript that currently loads my partials into the templates.

The problem is that it only seems to work on a one-layer basis. If I click my parent nav item Trends, and click a tab, the plugin doesn't work. Its like it refuses to see it.

I can see the BBQ plugin has advanced features, but I'm not sure if what I want is even advanced.

Can anyone suggest from the jQuery, or previous experience with the plugin what I could do?

Much appreciated.

Thanks,

Geoff

Answer (score 0):

You probably want 'two layers', as in 'two menus'... The more advanced example on jquery-bbq's website is maybe what you are looking for:
http://benalman.com/code/projects/jquery-bbq/examples/fragment-advanced/